# My SQL > is is possible to rollback the "CREATE DATABASE" statement?

Tags: mysql, ddl, rollback

I intended to create several databases and grant priviledges to the corresponding users. For instance,

```
CREATE DATABASE DB1;
GRANT .. ON .. TO DB1;
CREATE DATABASE DB2;
GRANT .. ON .. TO DB2;
CREATE DATABASE DB3;
GRANT .. ON .. TO DB3;
```

But I want to do it so that if any of this statement failed, all the previous statement like "CREATE DATABASE" or "GRANT ..." should be canceled like ROLLBACK of the transactional statements

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rollback using Mysql workbench.
Toad For Mysql support the rollback options, you can download it from the below website:

http://toad-for-mysql.en.softonic.com/

Answer (score 0):

Neither CREATE TABLE, nor GRANT statement can be rolled back within mysql using standard rollback command, see mysql documentation on [commands that cause implicit commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html).

You have to manually rollback these statements by dropping the created database objects and revoking access rights granted.

Some mysql manager applications may have such features, but those also rely on manually undoing the commands.